# How to calculate two averages of the same class, and get two outputs?

Tags: javascript

i am stuck in a little situation. I am making a plugin for my school grades to calculate the average.(The avarage might look rong but that's how our'e greades work.)The school site that show the grades is using the same class names. Until now i know how to calculate the average of 1 part.

But is there a way to call  2 classes in a `querySelectorAll`. like this: [0], [1]?

```
<script
            var matches = document.querySelectorAll(".course_eval_cell");
            console.log(matches);

            let up = 0;
            let down = 0;

            matches.forEach(function(fraction) {
                var divided = fraction.innerHTML.split("/");
                console.log(divided);
                up += parseInt(divided[0]);
                down += parseInt(divided[1]);
                console.log(up);
                console.log(down);
            });

            var result =   (up / down ) * 100  
            console.log(result);
            var result_fixed = result.toFixed(1) + "%";
            console.log(result_fixed);
            document.write('<p id="jstext">' + result_fixed + '</p>');

</script>


<div class="course_eval_row cf" style="width:770px;">
    <div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">10/10</div>
    <div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade  ">88/100</div>
</div>  

<div class="course_eval_row cf" style="width:770px;">
    <div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">4/10</div>
    <div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade  ">34/50</div>
</div>
```

I expect 2 different results, the average of the first grades and the average of the second grades. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It is valid class `.course_eval_cell-1, .course_eval_cell-2`

Comment: The problem is that i am adding this code with ```TamperMonkey```, so i can't change the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

```
<script>
    var matches = document.querySelectorAll(".course_eval_row");
    console.log(matches);    

    matches.forEach(function(fraction) {
      var subNodes = fraction.querySelectorAll(".course_eval_cell");
      let up = 0;
      let down = 0;
      subNodes.forEach(function(sub) {
          var divided = sub.innerHTML.split("/");
          console.log(divided);
          up += parseInt(divided[0]);
          down += parseInt(divided[1]);
          console.log(up);
          console.log(down);
        });
      var result =   (up / down ) * 100  
      console.log(result);
      var result_fixed = result.toFixed(1) + "%";
      console.log(result_fixed);
      document.write('<p id="jstext">' + result_fixed + '</p>');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It didn't work, the first result is fine ```98/110 => 89.1%```, but the second result it doesn't start the count from zero. So it does ```136/170 => 80.0%``` while it should be ```38/60 => 63%```. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

I think something more like this is whats needed:

```js
const calculateAverage = (elem) => {
  const arrGrade = Array.from(elem.querySelectorAll('.hasGrade')).map(({innerText: txt})=> {
    const score = txt.split('/')[0];
    const max = txt.split('/')[1];
    return score/max;
  });
  return arrGrade.reduce((a,v) => a+=v)/arrGrade.length;
};

var matches = document.querySelectorAll(".course_eval_row");

matches.forEach(m => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = `Average - ${calculateAverage(m)}`;
  m.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
.course_eval_row {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="course_eval_row cf" style="width:770px;">
    <div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">10/10</div>
    <div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade  ">88/100</div>
</div>  

<div class="course_eval_row cf" style="width:770px;">
    <div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade" smsctip="true">4/10</div>
    <div class="course_eval_cell hasGrade  ">34/50</div>
</div>
```

Comment: At your solution the average is calculated rong, it's about grade so an 8/100 is worse than a 4/10

Comment: Each grade is calculated as a percentage. 4/10 == 40%. The % is then averaged, why is that wrong?